# default admin password for local db2 database

Tags: db2

I have installed db2 on my local windows system. From what I have researched, I found that db2admin is the user name. I can't find the password. What is the default user name and password to login as a db2 admin?

Comment: There is no default, you specify during installation if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

DB2 always uses the authentication of the underlying operating system. This means there are no DB2 users (and passwords). The user db2admin can be created during installation. There is a field to specify its password.
If you don't remember it administer the user from the OS side.